# cmake: install header order and dependencies on target

Tags: cmake

I've a set of libraries and executables all with their own CMakeLists.txt. All libraries are building their targets to the same path (for example `../build/bin` and `../build/lib`)... as well as exporting their header files (`../build/inc`).

Now I wish to build one build system and let CMake figure out the dependencies (using `add_subdirectory` and global build settings).

The problem is: all libraries do export their headers to `build/inc` after they are build (when `make install` in invoked). When I do a whole system build `make install` is not invoked until after the end (and everything has build). So for example executable `progfoo` with `target_link_libraries( progfoo onelib )` will fail, because CMake figures out the dependency to `onelib` (which builds fine), but `progfoo` fails because it looks for headers in `build/inc`... which were not exported yet. The same thing in general applies to many libraries.

What is the correct CMake-Way to handle these cases? Thank you!

Comment: You should tell the sub-project where the includes from the other components are located, so in the source directory. And all libraries must be known to CMake, than it can figure out the right order of building them. I am not sure whether will fit in your layout.

Comment: As @usr1234567 already sad, you should include headers from their original location (see my answer). If later you still need all files in one place you can gather them, that's how CMake is supposed to be used. If you do not fight against it, it is a very usefull tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install is the final step, the one that should be visible to the user. So when you export binaries and headers you should already have binaries built against headers in their **original locations**.

From CMake point of view you have only 1 target at a time. For example you can build a Web Server and using as dependencies `libcurl` and `boost::asio`. It is very possible (and good) to add dependencies to current target using `add_subdirectory`, but when you have to add include directories you have to do that on a per dependency basis, it would be convenient in example if each of the dependencies provides already a variable with current absolute path to includes.

In example see this dummy **libcurl's CMakeLists.txt** that set path to absolute include directory

```
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)

// export into parent scope libcurl header location
set (LIBCURL_INCLUDES ${_DIR}/include PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Then you can use it from **Web Server's CMakeLists.txt** for building and later use the same path again to extract files for installing them where required

```
add_subdirectory(PATH_TO_LIBCURL_CMAKELISTS)

# add include directories for building web server
include_directories( ${LIBCURL_INCLUDES})

#I assume you are installing headers because final user will need them,
#in case you needed them just for building you are already done here
#without even installing them

#gather headers list
file(GLOB libCurlHeadersList
    "${LIBCURL_INCLUDES}/*.h"
    "${LIBCURL_INCLUDES}/*.hpp"
    )


#install header list
install( FILES
         ${libCurlHeadersList}
         DESTINATION ../build/inc/libcurl
       )
```